# How to create a distribution matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have below-mentioned dataframe in R:

```
DF <- tibble::tribble(
    ~ID, ~Check,
  "I-1",   "A1",
  "I-2",   "A2",
  "I-2",   "OT",
  "I-2",   "LP",
  "I-3",   "A1",
  "I-3",   "A2",
  "I-4",     NA,
  "I-5",     NA,
  "I-6",   "A1",
  "I-6",   "OT",
  "I-7",   "A2"
  )

DF2 <- tibble::tribble(
    ~ID,     ~Remarks,
  "I-1", "{X1,XR,XT}",
  "I-2",    "{X2,XR}",
  "I-3",           NA,
  "I-4", "{X1,XR,X2}",
  "I-5",       "{X1}",
  "I-6",       "{XT}",
  "I-7",    "{X1,X2}"
  )
```

Using the above mentioned two dataframe, I need the output in the following format:

Where I want to identify the exclusive count of `Check` for each unique `ID` and Identify what is the `Remark` value for that unique `ID` in 2x2 Matrix format.

`Group` Variable is where multiple values hit for a unique `ID`

Note - The order of rows should be highest to lowest based on `Exclusive_Count` of `Check`. It is quite possible that the number of unique `Check` and `Remark` may differ in my actual dataframe. (i.e 10 unique `Remark` and 5 `Check`, something like this)

It would be helpful if we can fix the value of `Remark` and `Check` as constant so that if that particular value is not available then the value for that will be 0.

DF_Output<-

```
Remark   Exclusive_Count  %       Blank  A1  A2  OT  LP
Blank    1               14.29%     1    0   0   0   0
X1       1               14.29%     2    0   1   1   0
X2       0               0.00%      1    1   0   1   1
XR       0               0.00%      0    1   1   0   1
XT       1               14.29%     0    0   1   1   0
Group    4               57.14%     1    2   2   2   1    
Total    7               100.00%    4    2   3   3   2
```

Comment: @RonakShah- I want the distribution of `Remarks` across all unique `Checks`. For Example, a unique `ID` having `Remarks` X1 matches with which all `Checks`. As mentioned in the output response, `X1` has `Checks` with two different `Checks` variable  A2 and OT.